# What does Concurrency mean in Siege and how is it calculated?

Tags: siege

I am new to siege and I am so confused by the Concurrency in siege result.
In FAQ, https://www.joedog.org/siege-faq/#a17a, its formula is very simple.
Completed transactions / elapsed time.

But when I check out https://www.joedog.org/siege-manual/#a08, the data is not correct.

Also, I found transaction rate. What is the difference between Concurrency and transaction rate.

Can anybody help to clarify this? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/JoeDog/siege/tree/master/src source code 
main.c and client.c shows us how this concurrency is calculated.